# Centrar div dentro de un form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo haciendo un formulario de 2 columnas, y quiero que los formularios queden centrados dentro del recuadro azul (ver imagen), y además de ello, el botón del send lo quiero debajo del formulario, se que es por el `display: flex` que tengo en la clase principal, pero no se como podría situar bien esos contenedores, si le agrego el `display: flex` a los inputs esta propiedad me sitúa mis inputs en lineal, cosa que no quiero

El código que tengo lo dejo después de la imagen.

Muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar

```css
.form-container {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 60%;
    // color: aqua;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 35px 55px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 35px 55px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: -1px 35px 55px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

    .inputs {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;       
    }

label {

    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    background-color: white;
    color: #DADCE0;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 0;
            }
            
input {
               
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid #DADCE0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  outline: none;
  background: none;

  }

.title {
        font-weight: bold;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        // margin-top: 30px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

.wrapper-left{
            background-color: rgba(81, 81, 81, 0);
            // width: 70%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
}

        .wrapper-right {
            // font-size: x-large;
            background-color: rgba(81, 81, 81, 0);
            // width: 70%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

.form-input {
            // position: relative;
            // height: 45px;
            width: 40%;
            margin-bottom: 17px; 
        }
```

```html
<div class="form-container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title-header">Create product</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="inputs">
        <div class="wrapper-left">
            <div class="center-wrapper">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="">Product Name</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="">Price</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="">Description</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="wrapper-right">
            <div class="center-wrapper">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="">Product Name</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="">Price</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label for="">Description</label>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="button-send">
            <button>SEND</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Santiago, que versión de bootstrap estás utilizando?

Comment: La imagen que estás mostrando es el resultado que quieres tener?

Comment: hola @Cris223511.dev estoy usando la versión 5.2.3
la imagen que estoy mostrando es diciendo que esos inputs y labels que tengo definidos allí quiero que se centren dentro del recuadro azul

Comment: Ah ok está bien, perfecto.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu objetivo, quieres tener dos formularios en pantalla, y un botón de send para cada uno justo en medio de los dos? O es un 1 solo formulario que divides en 2 columnas?

Comment: es un formulario que divido en 2 columnas y allí adjunto una imagen del espacio que hay en cada clase div, dentro del recuadro azul es donde quiero centrar mis inputs